# awesomewm - Dualscreen Problem with VirtualBox

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I have a problem with Virtualbox VM windows when I use a dualscreen configuration. I want to have the VM windows on the right hand screen, however, the window always "jumps" to the left hand screen if the resolution of the VM changes or if the virtual monitor switchs to standby.

```
s2 = screen:count() 
...
 { rule = { class = "VirtualBox Machine" }, 
   properties = { screen = s2,tag = "8 VM" } },
```

Does somebody know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but it sounds like you need

```
client.disconnect_signal("request::geometry", awful.ewmh.client_geometry_requests)
```

Somewhere in `rc.lua`. This disables the ability of an application to move itself around.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this fixes the problem.